# How can I specify the iteration path for the bugs rasied on a failed build?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

We use the option on build definitions to automatically create a bug upon build failure, which is awesome... until we set up to use separate teams within the project, for different focuses (e.g. BI / Client / Server), as they are separate teams, they have their own iterations.

Whenever a bug is being automatically created, it is being assigned to the build initiator (yay!), and it is being automatically assigned to a current iteration, but it is assigning to an iteration for a team the build initiator is not in (boo!)

I'm assuming that I can force Iteration by using the "Additional fields" options within the build definition, it's unclear if the iteration path can be set here (or if it can, how)? - From what I can see in the [documentation on work item fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=azure-devops) implies the iteration path is read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming that I can force Iteration by using the "Additional fields" options within the build definition, it's unclear if the iteration path can be set here (or if it can, how)?

You can use the additional fields `System.IterationPath` to specify the iteration path for the bugs rasied on a failed build:

[image]

After build failed (My current iteration is `MyTestProject\Iteration 1`):

[image]

Hope this helps.